# why doesn't subclass variable get changed when called superclass methods c++

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures, linked-list, strategy-pattern

```
class LinkedList : public IDataList {
    public :
        Node *head;
        Node* lastNode;
        int _size = 0;

    public : LinkedList() {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->lastNode = nullptr;
        }
        void deAppend(int data) override;

};
```

Then I have a circular linkedList which is the subclass of LinkedList

```
class CircularLinkedList : public LinkedList {
    public :
        Node *head;
        Node* lastNode;
        int _size = 0;

    public : CircularLinkedList() {
        this->head = nullptr;
        this->lastNode = nullptr;
    }
    void deAppend(int data) override;
};
```

This is the method deAppend which adds to the front of the list

```
void LinkedList::deAppend(int data){
    if (this->head== nullptr){
        Node *newNode = new Node(data, nullptr);
        this->head = newNode;
        this->lastNode = newNode;
    }else{
        Node *newNode = new Node(data, this->head);
        this->head = newNode;
    }

    this->_size+=1;
}
```

This is my CiruclarLinkedList calling deAppend method

```
void CircularLinkedList::deAppend(int data) {
    LinkedList::deAppend(data);
    this->lastNode->next = this->head;
}
```

The fact is why doesn't the lastNode and the head of CircularLinkedList variables change even though I am calling the method LinkedList::deAppend(data) and changing them in there. IDataList is just an interface.

```
class IDataList {
    public:
        virtual void deAppend(int data) = 0;
};
```

[Picture of Variables assignments after the method is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uovGZ.png)

Comment: The `LinkedList` and `CircularLinkedList` both have their own set of the variables, which just happens to be named the same thing. They variables are still separate and distinct. That is, `CircularLinkedList::head` is a separate variable from `LinkedList::head`, and they are not related in any way.

Comment: Basically delete the three lines in your CircularLinkedList class declaration that declare the duplicated variables. Delete these lines from CircularlInkedList: `Node *head; Node* lastNode; int _size = 0;`

Comment: Also `CircularLinkedList()` should be `CircularLinkedList() : LinkedList() { }` or `using LinkedList();`. And if you use `class LinkedList : public IDataList { public : Node *head =nullptr; Node* lastNode = nullptr; int _size = 0; void deAppend(int data) override; };` then you don't need any constructor at all. PS: `Node **lastNode = &head;` works much better.

Comment: "*Also `CircularLinkedList()` should be ...*" - or `CircularLinkedList() = default;`, or simply omitted altogether and let the compiler auto-generate a default constructor for you, since `LinkedList()` is default-constructible.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I just switched from Python to C++. It's weird but it makes sense now. I am trying a strategy pattern let's see how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are declaring your variables twice. I mean inside your base class you declare:

```
public:
Node *head;
Node* lastNode;
int _size = 0;
```

When a class inherits from another class publicly, all the public variables of the base class are also declared in the sub class. Which means you already had these variables in your `CircularLinkedList` class but you declared them again. Now you have two of them and you're changing the ones from your base class. remove the declaration from `CircularLinkedList`.